# Do Google (gstatic) font URLs change?

Tags: html, css, fonts, web-frontend

I'd like to link to Google fonts in my own CSS (rather than the Google-hosted CSS) files. Do these font filenames change or are they actually static?  For example, Open Sans is at:

https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01m4X0hVgzZQUfRDuZrPvH3D8.woff2

and Lato is at:

https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/8qcEw_nrk_5HEcCpYdJu8BTbgVql8nDJpwnrE27mub0.woff2

Can I reference that URL from my stylesheet, or is there risk of that URL changing?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the documented approach (`<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
</style>`)?

Comment: Trying to reduce the number of HTTP connections/DNS lookups. The CSS gets served from googleapis.com and the fonts are served from gstatic.com.